# How to resolve conflict while merging branch automatically? in GitLab? do you want a yaml script, a CI action recipe, or just the git command?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

If I merge two branch.It shows,

```
Merge blocked: merge conflicts must be resolved
```

If I give resolve conflicts

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=**development**","-jar","/app/integration-service.jar"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=**stage**","-jar","/app/integration-service.jar"]
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: integration-app
  namespace: stellacenter-**dev**
  namespace: stellacenter-**stage-uat**
  labels:
    app: integration-app
spec:
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  integration-service
  namespace: stellacenter-**dev**
  namespace: stellacenter-**stage-uat**
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
```

It is the easy way to **use ours** in GitLab and commit to the source branch and done it , but I want to resolve the conflict automatically not manual while merging .Is there any thing to add like rules ? How to do .Please help me to sort out . I've attached yaml script which I'm using.

```
services:
  - docker:19.03.11-dind
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "developer" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "stage"|| ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i))
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "developer" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "stage"|| ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ (/^([A-Z]([0-9][-_])?)?SPRINT(([-_][A-Z][0-9])?)+/i))
      when: never 
stages:
  - build
  - Publish
  - deploy
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - target
build_jar:
  image: maven:3.8.3-jdk-11
  stage: build
  script: 
    - mvn clean install package -DskipTests=true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
docker_build:
  stage: Publish
  image: docker:19.03.11
  services:
    - docker:19.03.11-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
  script: 
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_TAG
deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: stellacenter/aws-helm-kubectl
  before_script:
    - aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${DEV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
    - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${DEV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    - aws configure set region ${DEV_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
  script:
    - sed -i "s/<VERSION>/${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}/g" appointment-service.yml
    - mkdir -p  $HOME/.kube
    - cp $KUBE_CONFIG_DEV $HOME/.kube/config
    - chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config 
    - export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
    - kubectl apply -f appointment-service.yml
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to me. A merge conflict, by its very nature, requires human eyes to determine what the correct results should be.

Comment: If you're working in a script, yes, there probably is a way to do it. You might be to qualify the question: do you want a bash script, a CI action recipe, or just the git command?

Comment: We are using yaml script for deployment. That's why I'm asking , whether can we add rules ?will work? @joanis

Comment: Can you share the part of your yaml script that does the merging?

Comment: I've updated @joanis

Comment: Good, I believe your question is now answerable. Now I hope someone knows the answer  around here! Just one detail, that was a strange edit, putting my question to you in the title... I meant you should tell us whether you want bash/yaml/ci/git cmd, putting your answer to my question into your question, rather than copying my question to you in the question itself. :)

Comment: Thank you @joanis .Now I want to something to know , If I merge the branch , conflicts happens, If I cleared that, the destination will change right!!! but I want unmerged files also like ( for eg: merge request from dev(source branch) to stage(destination)--->conflicts ----->cleared----->any how the destination branch will change but I want the changed branch (changed files) as well unchanged branch files like (before merging )for eg: merge dev to stage---->I want dev files & dev merged to stage files and also stage files (unmerged file also)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *automatic* way to do this during a merge or MR pipeline. There is also no way to detect a conflict using `rules:` or similar. You will need to fix the conflict manually.

If you had a way (e.g. a script) to reliably resolve a conflict through a series of repeatable commands, you *might* be able to automate that by using a CICD job.

For example, you might use the `$CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS` or `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID` to find the open merge request, then use the [merge requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr) to determine if a conflict exists, then if a conflict exists, take some actions to fix the conflict, then push the fixes to the source branch.

Example:

```yaml
fix-conflicts:
  stage: .pre # run before all other stages
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID'
      
  script:
    # use the MR API to detect if there is a conflict. You implement this script.
    # if no conflicts exist (nonzero script exit) - exit 0 for the job
    - ./does-mr-conflict-exist.sh $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID || exit 0
    # you implement this script to fix the conflict
    - ./fix-conflicts.sh
    - git push -u origin "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME"
    - exit 1  # optional - stop the pipeline (a new one will be created from push)
```

Comment: Thank you @sytech .Now I want to something to know , If I merge the branch , conflicts happens, If I cleared that, the destination will change right!!! but I want unmerged files also like ( for eg: merge request from dev(source branch) to stage(destination)--->conflicts ----->cleared----->any how the destination branch will change but I want the changed branch (changed files) as well unchanged branch files like (before merging )for eg: merge dev to stage---->I want dev files & dev merged to stage files and also stage files (unmerged file also)